# Vector Calculus, Show four points are coplanar and vertices of a parallelogram

Tags: calculus

Show that the four points $r_1 = (1, 0, 1), r_2 = (4, 3, 5), r_3 = (6, 4, 6)$ and $r_4 = (3, 1, 2)$ are coplanar and the vertices of a parallelogram. Let S be the closed planar region given by the interior and boundary of this parallelogram. An arbitrary point of S can be written as the convex linear combination
$r = \sum_{j = 1}^{4}\alpha_jr_j$ and $\sum_{j = 1}^{4} \alpha_j = 1$
for $0 \leq \alpha_j \leq 1$

Show that the vertices, edges and interior of the rectangle $R = [0, 1]×[0, 1]$
are mapped onto the vertices, edges and interior of S by the linear map
(parametrization) $\mathbb{r}: R \to S$

$\mathbb{r}(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) = (1 + 3u + 2v, 3u + v, 1 + 4u + v),         (u, v) ∈ [0, 1] × [0, 1]$

Comment: Seems to me you are asking more than one question. As for the parallelogram, use the distance formula to determine two pairs of congruent sides. Then find an equation ot the plane of three points and use point substitution to confirm that the fourth points lies on it as well. Give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Fun to sketch, yes the points are coplanar and the vertices of a parallelogram.

In fact, the points lie in the plane: $ -x + 5y - 3z + 4 = 0 $ (This requires just that you eliminate the variables u and v from the defining equations and express your result in terms of the relationship between x ,y , z.

Comment: May I ask what program produced the image?

Comment: "Grapher" -- It should be in the utility folder on a  Macintosh.

Comment: Thanks! Are you able to explain what you mean in a little bit more detail so my tired brain can comprehend

Comment: First, see what happens when you map (0,0) , (0,1) , (1,0), (1,1) (the (u , v) coordinates) with the defining equations:

$$x = 1 + 3u + 2v$$
$$y = 3u + v$$
$$z = 1 + 4u + v$$

onto S. 

You should get back the $r_j$ points. Next , try to eliminate u and v from the defining equations, you should get the equation for the plane. There is more to this question, ( yes, you can express any point in the convex region by weighting things correctly, and so on. Also, try to verify that the shape is a parallelogram